# Angular console.log() shows line in index.js and not in typescript file

Tags: angular, debugging

I have a bug in my Angular application. For some reason its not showing me the source of the bug line from the TS file, but only writes the bug is the "index.js" file, line number 3573. This line is something very general, and I can't seem to locate my problematic code line.

I tried to write lines to the console.log(), but it still shows the "index.js" line number and not the TS file line number.

How can I fix to show the code line number from the TS file?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you call some functionality in the wrong way, or with wrong parameters.  the internal framework catches some unknown state and alerts you.  you could try to use `debugger` in your code (chrome dev tools) and try to trace to the point where you go from your code to the framework and trigger this error